Why is my svchost.exe (NetworkService -p) receiving so much data on my Windows 10 machine?
I have a very slow connection, and when this is happening, it can make playing games impossible for up to an hour. The only way I can stop it is by going into the Resource Monitor and suspending the process. Does anyone know why this happens so frequently on my Windows 10 machine, yet never on my Windows 11 machine, or do you know how I can prevent this? I have automated updates disabled, so I'm not sure why this seems to be downloading for hours on end.

Which services does this specific process host? Use ProcExp or SysInformer or tasklist /svc to find out.

Can you check what Event Viewer says around the time the Network Service starts using the data? You might even be able to use Process Explorer (by Microsoft) to see more details about the running process while it is downloading as well. If Windows updates are stopped, do you see anything else happening on the system that would indicate WHAT the service is busy downloading?
